# How to resolve Error" Account: Multiple items found. Select from drop-down or click icon to refine search."?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi In Opportunity Related Account Vf Page,Account is lookup field.When ever i select rep/agent no,acoount role i am mapping account name (through lookuppopup vfpage (And some other functionality is there according to account role)).when ever i click save button it is showing above error even though Rep/agent 368 is having single account, but with that account name multiple accounts are there.How To resolve this error?

I am sharing screenshots for referrence:
1.[image]
2.After click Save Button:[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, that you have reproduced the standard lookup popup window (and I really do not understand why). It is a bad practice to rewrite the standard SFDC functionality if you can just reuse it in your code.

Your custom lookup window takes the `Name` of the account and set it to the input field. Additionally it tries to set the selected account-ID into the `accsection:accfield_lkid` but it **definitely goes wrong**... So the system tries to identifies the account based on the text entered, and found multiple records with that name.

So what you could do is to assign the selected account based on `ID` per apex method and NOT based on it `Name` because it is NOT unique.

Otherwise the user should select wished account manually from the list.